# center a div of div within it without using margin auto

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position

tried text-align center and margin auto, both doesn't work and I do not want to used to use the 'margin hack' for centering..

http://jsfiddle.net/st9AM/1/

```
.circle{

float: left;
position: relative;
width: 120px;
height: 120px;
border-radius: 50%;
border: 2px solid #DDD;
}

.inner{
float: left;
position: relative;
width: 60px;
height: 60px;
border-radius: 50%;
border: 2px solid #DDD;
}
```

Comment: why without `margin auto`?

Comment: are the elements going to have a fixed size? always 120px and 60px?

Comment: which part do you want in center? "+" sign or inner circle or both?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, using `margin: auto;` is **not** a hack

And to center your circle inside the circle, you can use positioning techniques, like `position: absolute;`. Here, I am using `position: absolute;` on the inner circle, than am assigning `top` and `left` properties with a value of `50%` and than am using `margin-top` and `margin-left` and deducting 1/2 of the `height` and `width`.

Why am deducting `32px`? As I already said am deducting exactly half the total `width` and `height` so this also includes the `border` of your element which is set to `2px` which makes your element `64px` in `height` and `width` respectively.

To `vertical-align` the `+` symbol, am using `line-height` property as I can only see a single character to be vertically aligned(you didn't said but technically I can assume what shape are you looking for), alternatively you can also use `vertical-align: middle;` but you need to set the container element to `display: table-cell;`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/st9AM/7/)

---

Last but not the least, you should nest the `span` tag inside the inner circle `div`.

```
.circle{
   float: left;
   position: relative;
   width: 120px;
   height: 120px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   border: 2px solid #DDD;
}

.inner{
   text-align: center;
   line-height: 60px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   margin-top: -31px;
   left: 50%;
   margin-left: -31px;
   width: 60px;
   height: 60px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   border: 2px solid #DDD;
}
```

Comment: If you cannot change your DOM than you can ping me for help

Comment: +1 Just a thing, the border is actually 2px so the total width would be 64px and the margin -32px

Comment: @koala_dev ohhh the math :( thanks for pointing it out, I thought it was 1 :) will just edit my answer...

Comment: u made my day, God bless u:)

Answer (score 3):

[**Here's**](http://jsfiddle.net/st9AM/12/) a cleaner solution.

with one HTML element only.

**HTML:**

```
<div class='circle'></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.circle, .circle:after
{
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px solid #DDD;
    text-align: center;
}
.circle
{
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    font-size: 0;
}
.circle:before {
    content:'';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.circle:after
{    
    content:'+';
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 20px 0; /* 2*padding + font size = innerCircle height*/
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Nyc solution,  you get my vote,  gut I avoid using pseudo unless required, users dont understand that :-D

Answer (score 1):

You had "float: left" in the inner circle, which you didn't need

```
//float: left;
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/st9AM/5/)

Answer (score 1):

remove float left and use margin: 0 auto;

```
 .circle{

         position: relative;
         width: 120px;
         height: 120px;
         border-radius: 50%;
         border: 2px solid #DDD;
         margin:0 auto;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/st9AM/11/). You wrote `float:left;` and wanted to center the image. Remove the `float:left;` and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Current browsers (May-22) work with this (replace 261px and 165x by 50% of your image size... mine is 522px x 330px ):

```
{
  position:absolute;
  left: calc( 50% - 261px );
  top: calc( 50% - 165px );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much to editors. Hadn't realized they were suggesting the change of formatting of my code proposal. 100% agreed.